# Identify start and stop of events according to their ID number

Tags: excel, relation

In Excel, I have Column A with ID number. Suppose:

```
1001  
1002  
1003  
2001  
1002  
1001  
2002  
1002
```

in A1 to A8. Now I want to identify where `2001` starts and ends with `2002`.
Meaning values corresponding to `1001` in B1 will be zero (since `2001` is not detected). Similarly for `1002`, `1003` will be 0. So B1, B2, B3 = 0.
Now B4 should be one, since A4=`2001`. Values B5 onwards will continue to be one for all following values of A till `2002` is sensed, ie A7. 
Again following values will be 0 till `2001` is sensed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of these should do.

```
=IFERROR(--(INDEX(A$1:A1, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:1)/(A$1:A1>2000), 1))=2001), 0)
=IFERROR(--OR(A$1:A1=2002, INDEX(A$1:A1, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:1)/(A$1:A1>2000), 1))=2001), 0)
```

[image: Identify start and stop of events according to their ID no]

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I have tried both, but they give error value- Zero. Where should I modify in formula?

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess it just doesn't work on your computer.